# Require module and Create object in multiple places

Tags: node.js, express, npm

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
```

This question is with the example of express module but this could be for any module in which you require the module and use the constructor.

So the generic code is

```
var M = require('M'); 
var myM = M();
```

and my question is that in my code(in the routers files) i am using the above 2 lines in many files.

So

1. Is this the correct way of using modules,Should each module be required and constructed(by constructor) in one place and then the constructed object be used throughout the code?
2. What are the side effects of using modules like i have used(extra RAM usage,latency ..)?

Comment: That enormously depends on what `M` is doing.  A more concrete example might make this answerable.

Comment: your question subject makes it sound like you are planning to ask about using the `express` module more than once, but your question body appears to be asking about the usage of `require`, not about `express` specifically.

Comment: @AaronDufour the express module itself can be taken as example.

Comment: @Claies the question was meant to ask about any module in general which has its associated data and methods.Would the requiring of such a module and creating an object in multiple places in the codebase be a problem was the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) *Is this the correct way of using modules?*

There's two parts to this:

- Should each module `require()` the other modules it depends upon, even if multiple modules have a dependency in common?

  Yes. That is the norm in NodeJS. (Explained further for #2.)

  And, it'll continue to be the norm as the native [`import`/`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) become available for use.
- Should they then be constructed?

  That depends on the individual module and whether it exposes a constructor/factory/etc. You'll have to refer to the module's own documentation for that.

  But, having a constructor/factory/etc. is the exception more than the norm. The default export from a module is just an Object, which will often have methods attached to it. Most of the [core modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/) follow that form.

---

> 2) What are the side effects of using modules like i have used

Again, two parts:

- There should be no additional consumption from the `require()`. After each file is evaluated, it's `module.exports` [is cached](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_caching), so subsequent requires of it will just be given the same value from cache.
- The factory/constructor, however, will likely create more objects and consume more memory with each use.

---

With Express specifically:

- It can be useful to `require('express')` in multiple files to define different parts of your application, especially through `express.Router`s. This can help you organize your application.
- It's only necessary to invoke the factory function multiple times if you would like to define your application as a series of sub-applications or define multiple applications to run at the same time.

Comment: Ok so from your answer i get that
1.Requiring a module at several places is absolutely ok.
2.Using an object of the module would be ok if it exposes methods only.
3.If the object of module has data attributes then it is not preferable to create multiple objects.